# Starting SVN server at system boot

Tags: linux, boot, svn, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a [Raspberry Pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) Model B with [Raspbian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Software). I installed the SVN server and tested it with

```
svnserve -d -r /home/pi/external_hdd/svn_root
```

It works, it accepts connections and makes users checkout and commit their work.

Now, I don't want to manually start the server every time I power off and then power back on my Raspberry Pi, so I would like to make `svnserve` start at boot.

I went to the console and typed:

```
cd /etc/init.d
sudo touch svnserve
sudo nano svnserve

------------------ START of the Nano window ------------------

#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          svnserve
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# X-Interactive:     true
# Short-Description: Start/stop svnserve
### END INIT INFO
svnserve -d -r /home/pi/external_hdd/svn_root

------------------- END of the Nano window -------------------

^O         # Pressed CTRL-O to save the file
Return     # Confirmed to save into the svnserve file
^X         # Exited nano

chmod u+x /etc/init.d/svnserve
```

So this way I created my startup script and marked it as executable.

Then I used the `update-rc.d` to add the script to startup:

```
sudo update-rc.d svnserve defaults
```

The output is:

```
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
insserv: warning: script 'mathkernel' missing LSB tags and overrides
```

This is the first time I try to add a script to startup; what is this error?

I've seen some forum where users had the same problem, and they said that the first part (the init part) of the script was missing, and that adding it would have solved the issue. The fact is that I have it, and it still doesn't work.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I am just starting with Rasperian (Just powered my first rPi half an hour ago) but: Are you sure that the shebang line (`#!/bin/bash`) is the first in the script. E.g. no empty lines above it?

Comment: @Hennes Yes. Actually, it's not an issue with my script. I googled around and found [this](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=68263), which states it's a bug in the `mathkernel` file under `/etc/init.d`. In fact it doesn't have the init section at the beginning of the file. I did the fix described in the answer and solved it :)